Can Remmina turn on the 'grab all keyboard events' setting at session start?
I have Remmina working nicely with various remote machines (RDP, VNC). One feature I use a lot is the "Grab all keyboard events" toggle:

This setting allows the host to pass the ⊞ Win key directly into the remote machine, rather than the host capturing it.
Is there a way to start a session with the "grab" setting ON to begin with?  I have to toggle it ON each time I start a session, and really have no reason to ever turn it off.
